# Make ul-li navigation dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="keyitem">keyitem 1</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li class="keyitem">keyitem 2</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li class="keyitem"></li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But i want to make the above like following:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="keyitem">one
        <ul>
          <li class="child_one">item</li>
          <li class="child_one">item</li>
          <li class="child_one">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="keyitem">two
        <ul>
          <li class="child_two">item</li>
          <li class="child_two">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="keyitem">three
        <ul>
          <li class="child_three">item</li>
          <li class="child_three">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***Not possible to change the first snippet of code structure. I have to make the first snippet like second snippet and replace with the first one.***

please help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Must the text `keyitem 1` be replaced with `one` etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var childClasses = ['child_one', 'child_two', 'child_three' /* more here */];
$('#nav li.keyitem').each(function(i) {
    var $li = $(this),
        $sub = $li.nextUntil('li.keyitem').addClass(childClasses[i]);

    $('<ul />').appendTo($li).append($sub);
});
```

Will produce:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="keyitem">keyitem 1
        <ul>
          <li class="child_one">item</li>
          <li class="child_one">item</li>
          <li class="child_one">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="keyitem">keyitem 2
        <ul>
          <li class="child_two">item</li>
          <li class="child_two">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="keyitem">keyitem 3
        <ul>
          <li class="child_three">item</li>
          <li class="child_three">item</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/A5dGG/))